# How to lubricate and fix faucet handle

Tags: plumbing, faucet

I have that faucet and it's too stiff. By that I mean that to have the handle move a little, I have to apply a lot of strength, and I often "overshoot" so it splashes everywhere. I wanted to put some lubricant and I tried removing it, but it didn't work. I can't find the brand, but it looks old.

I removed a small Allen screw behind the whole thing and a flat head screw under the handle (when the main was closed) and it didn't help. When I tried putting the screw under the handle, it seems unaligned and I can't put it back in.

Anyone could tell me how to properly "dismantle" to clean and lubricate it, and how to put it back together? Do I need to remove it from the sink with the huge "bolt" from under the counter to do anything with it?

This is the logo:

[image]

This is the rest of the faucet (with the missing screw hole showing):
[image]